# fstab nouser - device still mounted

Tags: linux, unix, mount

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

The `nouser` option forbids an ordinary (i.e., non-root) user to mount the filesystem.  This is the default.

In my `/etc/fstab`, I have:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_sjoam-LogVol03  /u01  ext4  defaults  1 2
```

Even after I reboot my system, I can still see the mountpoint as a non-root user.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I still see the mount-point

I think you're misunderstanding what the `user` and `nouser` options actually do. They have nothing to do with the permissions of the filesystem itself and don't govern access to the filesystem.

They simply govern if a non-root user is allowed to run the `mount` command and mount the filesystem if it's not currently mounted. And that filesystem is automatically mounted, by the system, on boot.

Governing access to the filesystem should be done with the permissions of the mountpoint and the permissions of the filesystem itself.